# Dangling Reference to rvalue

Tags: c++, reference

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Int {
    const int& val;
};

Int test(){
    return Int {30};
}

int main()
{
    Int i = Int{30};

    cout << i.val << endl;

    Int j = test();

    cout << j.val << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `-std=c++11 -O2` will output:

```
30
0
```

And a warning:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:18:15: warning: '<anonymous>' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

     cout << j.val << endl;
```

Is `i.val` a dangling reference? As far as I understand, the `Int{30}` temporary will be destroyed at the semi-colon, and `i.val` will be bound to the temporary's `val` which has been destroyed already. Is it correct?

And why the compiler says `j` is uninitialized, and `j.val` is 0?

Comment: @montaldo, that's not what's he's asking

Comment: I compiled with g++ v4.8 without any warning and got two 30's as an output.

Comment: @Igor Compiling with `-O2 -Wall -pedantic` gives me the same output as OP, but without, same results as you.

Comment: @IgorPopov http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/645caddd7b9df37b Interesting that when I use `-O2`, it gives `30 0` and when I use `-O0`, it gives `30 30` and no warning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I initially gave wasn't correct with respect to the first reference: Although temporaries are generally destroyed at the end of a full-expression in which they are created, their life-time gets extended if a reference is bound to the temporary or to a subobject of the temporary unless there are a few specific case (according to 12.2 [class.temporary] paragraph 5):

1. A temporary bound to a reference member from the class's member initializer list is destroyed at the end of the constructor: the compiler has no chance to expand the temporary's life without storing the temporary as it can't see where the object will eventually live.
2. A temporary bound to a parameter in a function call lives until the end of the full-expression (as does the parameter; binding the parameter inside the function doesn't extend the temporaries life-time in any way).
3. When binding a temporary to a reference in the return statement returned reference doesn't extend its life-time, i.e., a stale reference will be returned (the only use for returning references is to return objects which held elsewhere and are not on the function's stack).
4. A temporary bound in a new initializer doesn't extend the life-time of the temporary as the live time of the created object cannot be predicated and the temporary would need to be allocated somewhere.

The is no clause prohibiting directly initializing a reference member with a temporary value as long as it doesn't use an initializer list. Furthermore the example to the item about the new initializer actually contains a similar example (12.2 [class.temporary] paragraph 5, example on the 4th bullet):

> ```
> struct S { int mi; const std::pair<int,int>& mp; };
> S a { 1, {2,3} };
> S* p = new S{ 1, {2,3} }; // Creates dangling reference
> ```

The example explicitly calls out that the reference initialized on the third line is dangling but doesn't do so on the second line. This isn't normative text but it seems to indicate that the second line is OK and the rules mentioned above would seem to make the line legal, too.

That is, the statement

```
Int i = Int{30};
```

initializes `i.val` and the temporary (the `int` constructed from `30`) is kept until `i` goes out of scope. On the other hand, the statement

```
return Int {30};
```

binds the temporary to a reference in a return statement and the third bullet applies: the life-time of the temporary is not extended beyond the end of the expression. This behavior is consistent with not extending the life-time of named objects even if a reference to these objects is returned.

Comment: The last sentence of this answer is the most relevant and maybe should be in bold and/or moved closer to the top of the answer. Life of a temporary (rvalue) is extended to the lifetime of `T const&` reference to which the temporary is bound, while `i.val` is actually of this type, but nested in a struct. Is there a relevant statements in the C++ standard with the claim of *invisibility* for the purpose of the lifetime extension as written in your last sentence?

Comment: @IgorPopov: Actually, my answer is wrong! Tracing through the various points it seems the rules changed and temporaries can be bound to reference members as long as they don't travel through a function call or a member initializer list (I'll correct my answer in a moment...)

Comment: This was written in another answer in this post but the author of the answer removed it. The relevant section of the standard is 12 something if I remember well.

Comment: Why would -O2 and -O0 produce different results?

Comment: @texasbruce: This code invokes undefined behavior. The compiler can do anything when confronted with undefined behavior and still be compliant with the standard.